# setTimeout inside for loop with Interval 0

Tags: javascript, settimeout

when I print "i" inside setTimeout with time diff 0. why does it print "n" the same number always?

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   setTimeout(function() {console.log(i)}, 0);
}
```

Output:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```